# Conditions that bound a series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I have the following problem to solve:

Let $u_{t}=\sum_{j=0}^{t}\frac{a_j}{1+r_j}$.

For $K$ sufficiently large, what conditions are necessary on $a_j$ and $1+r_j$ for $u_K$ to be bounded?

I really don't know how to attack the problem, what I have tried is to analyze by cases. For example, if $a_j$ is alternating then I could say that if $\frac{1}{1+r_j}$ satisfies the Cauchy criterion then the serie converges and is thus bounded, but I don't see what else I could do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $K\in\mathbb{N}$, $u_K$ is finite and thus bounded, regardless of the conditions on $a_j$ and $1+r_j$. In the case that $K\to\infty$, to make sure that the series $$\sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{a_j}{1+r_j}$$ is bounded, we just need to make sure that it is convergent. There are many tests that give us sufficient conditions for this. You mentioned considering $a_j=(-1)^j$ to obtain a alternating series which uses the alternating series test. If these $a_j, r_j$'s are non-negative then you can also use the integral test, in which case we just need $r_j$ to grow at least 2 powers faster than $a_j$. For example, $r_j=j^3$ and $a_j=j$.

The point is that, there are many tests which you can find in a calculus book for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, it seemed to me that there were many ways to analyze it. Could you share with me in the case of the integral test (assuming positivity), how do you get to that result, please?

Comment: If $a_n=f(n)$, where $f$ is positive, continuous and non-increasing on some interval $[N,\infty)$, $N\in\mathbb{N}$. Then the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$$ conveges if and only if the integral $$\int_N^\infty f(t)\, dt$$ converges

Comment: Using this theorem, if you let $a_j=j$ and $r_j=j^3$ then the function you are working with here is $$f(j)=\frac{j}{1+j^3}$$ This function is positive, non-increasing, continuous and its integral converges

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot!